# AIR how to prevent application descriptor file from reverting or updating on launch

Tags: air

I have a desktop application using NativeProcess and I need the follwoing in the descriptor file.

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>
```

Unfortunately the file keeps reverting to (desktop first)

```
<supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop </supportedProfiles>
```

How do I prevent this?
I'm using Flash Builder to launch though compiling using the Flash IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash CS is rewriting the list based on the order of the checkboxes in the AIR Settings window. Changing the order of the profiles in the Descriptor.3.x.xsd file won't help. You could set the app.xml file to read-only, as long you don't have to make any other changes. Not a great solution...